# How to hide Bootstrap 5 modal on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 modal, which is used to download a file by clicking a button. This works fine, but I want the modal to be hidden after clicking the download button, and this is where I'm struggling.

I am attempting to use `jQuery` to do this. I know that the `jQuery` library is successfully imported and that my function is being executed because I can display an alert box within the same function, but I can't get the modal to hide.

The full code snippet is pasted below with the script section at the bottom. The key line of code that I am trying to use to dismiss the modal is: -

```
$('#downloadConfirm1').modal({show : false});
```

I have also tried the following: -

```
$('.modal.in').modal('hide');
```

But neither has worked. I am extremely grateful to anyone who takes the time to read my post. Any suggestions most welcome!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Java Documentum Services</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-OvBgP9A2JBgiRad/mM36mkzXSXaJE9BEIENnVEmeZdITvwT09xnxLtT4twkCa8m/loMbPHsvPl0T8lRGVBwjlQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-GQGU0fMMi238uA+a/bdWJfpUGKUkBdgfFdgBm72SUQ6BeyWjoY/ton0tEjH+OSH9iP4Dfh+7HM0I9f5eR0L/4w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal"
           data-bs-target="#downloadConfirm1"
           role="button">Download
        </a>
    
        <div class="modal fade" id="downloadConfirm1" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="downloadConfirm1"
             aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="downloadModalLabel">Confirm download</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Download Docx_test_file.docx?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <a href="files/dummy.pdf" download="dummy.pdf">
                            <button type="button" id="download_button1">Download</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    
    <script>
    $('#download_button1').click(function() {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        $('#downloadConfirm1').modal({show : false});
    });
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 modal dropped jQuery so that is why you cannot hide the modal with jQuery. You should save your modal instance in the moment of initialization.

Afterwards you can use this code to hide your modal.

Ref: [Bootstrap 5 Modal#hide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#hide)

```
var modalInstance = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('downloadConfirm1'));

var modal = document.getElementById('downloadConfirm1'); 
modalInstance.hide(modal);
```

Comment: This really helped point me in the right direction of doing things the new way without jQuery - many thanks!

Comment: how about if you initialize modal by button click with data attributes? `data-bs-toggle="modal"` `data-bs-target="#modalId"`. How to close it then?

Comment: @koubin Check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#getinstance

You can close it by acquiring the modal instance and calling .hide() on it

Answer (score -1):

```
var myModalEl = document.querySelector('#scheduleMeetingModal');
var myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(myModalEl);
myModal.hide();
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the Low Quality Queue. Code only answers are not considered good answers, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are less useful to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / better than existing answers.

Comment: this was very helpful for me because I had the needed knowledge to understand it. In my case, I was trying to close a modal via javascript that had been triggered via the `data-bs-target` attribute, and your comment reminded me that what i needed was the bootstrap `modal.getInstance()` method. 

FWIW.